# maps and routes in D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js, bigdata

I'm trying to visualize a map of US flights and I'd like to do something similar to this
http://mbostock.github.io/d3/talk/20111116/airports.html

I know how to layout the GPS coordinates and flight destination and origin in D3 but I'm not sure how to show routes when someone hovers over an airport like the visualization above.

I looked around and couldn't find any good references. Any tips would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is. You can have a look at the source code of the example you've linked to to see how it's done.

Answer (score 0):

Nosayr,

What you need is a GeoChart component that can show connection lines between Markers. This is beautifully illustrated in the VectorWorkz GeoChart Demo here:
http://vectorworkz.com/demo/ (click on "Flight Routes" on the left)

The Markers in the demo are however positioned manually and not by lat/long.

Thanks,
Amar,
VectorWorkz.com